# Using bridged adapter function on VirtualBox with several Linux guests - will there be any IP conflict?

Tags: networking, ip

I have a few computers connected to one network, running Oracle VirtualBox with Linux. The host is Windows.

Will they have any IP conflict or issues like that (they are using bridged adapter function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not have an IP conflict. When you bridge the adapters, it will effectively operate as a switch, and two MAC-addresses will be visible to the partner connection. They will have separate MAC-addresses and IP-addresses.

Bridging effectively makes the VM sit directly on the hosts network adapter, as if it had its own physical adapter.

Comment: and if you know, will IP of briged addapter change after reboot of host or guest OS?

Comment: Depends on your setup. Commonly a DHCP server will hand out the IP the client had last it was seen, if it's still free. This is not a property of virtualization, but configuration of DHCP server and DHCP client.

Comment: ok, and where can i find configuration file of DHCP srver and DHCP client?

Comment: It depends. DHCP server is typically running on your router in a home network. But what do you want to **achieve**? That it has the same IP every time?

Comment: yes, i need to set static ip to my vbox guest os

Comment: Then you either make a DHCP reservation for the MAC-address of the virtual machine in your dhcp server (probably the router), or set a static IP on the virtual machine.

Comment: And for the future: [state what you want to achieve](http://xyproblem.info/).